# 403:Forbidden Error on sharepoint online rest api on reading /updating a sharepoint list

Tags: node.js, sharepoint-online, http-status-code-403, sharepoint-api

Im trying to connect my nodejs application to update/read list items from https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listname').

Using sharepoint addin authentication where app was registered onto xyz.sharepoint.com registration page.
with manifest file permission set for the app set to fullcontrol:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Following code is being used:

```
          var sprequest=require('sp-request')
          let spr = sprequest.create({          
                clientId:'clientid',  
                clientSecret:'client secret'  
            });
            spr.requestDigest('https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/dev')
            .then(digest => {
              return spr.post('https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'listname\')', {
                body: {
                  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' },
                  'Title': 'TesList'
                },

                headers: {
                  'X-RequestDigest': digest,
                  'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
                  'IF-MATCH': '*'
                }
              });
            })
            .then(response => {
              if (response.statusCode === 204) {
                console.log('List title updated!');
              }
            }, err => {
              if (err.statusCode === 404) {
                console.log('List not found!');
              } else {
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
```

I was able to get the authentication token but the POST request to the sharepoint online api(spr.post part in code)fails with 403:forbidden error.("Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.")
I also tried with postman and always end up with the same error.
I dont understand whats goin on anymore,could anyone help is it related to scope of the app? some issue in the manifest file?

App registration done in sharepoint online site as mentioned in the article-https://medium.com/@anoopt/accessing-sharepoint-data-using-postman-sharepoint-rest-api-76b70630bcbf

Reading the list also failed with same error via code and postman.